# how to define setInterval in loop?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, setinterval

I have sample code like this

```
        <input type="button" value="test" onclick="newfunc()"/>
        <br/>
        <div class="first">
            <input type="text" id="iid88" />
            <br />
        </div>
    <script>
function newfunc() {
    var one = document.getElementsByClassName('first')[0].querySelectorAll("[id^=iid]");
            for (var i = 0; i < one.length; i++)
            {
            setInterval(function () {
            one[i].value = 20;
            }, 1000);
            }
}
    </script>
```

i cannot get answer within input text box .
how can i resolve this problem ?

i see this page [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example) but here we dont have any setInterval usage in answers

Comment: *"i cannot get answer within input box"* what answer did you expect to get? Note that `setInterval` is **not** equivalent to a `Sleep` function in other languages

Comment: when we click on button , this click can show to us answer in second input text box within div tag

Comment: The answer was marked as a duplicate, but if it'll help, here's a fiddle that uses your code and that might help you along: https://jsfiddle.net/rk2t875t/

Comment: thank you @JosephMarikle , big thank you for your help in this difficult situation , by the way could you please say me how can i find role of this line : let k = i;

Comment: @radolf Sure.  [let](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) is newish to ecmascript. It allows the declaring of variables within a block scope.  It has [some issues with compatibility](http://caniuse.com/#search=let), but I find it fairly safe to use.  If let can't be used, you can either move the loop into the interval closure or pass it into the closure when the interval is kicked off using `bind`: https://jsfiddle.net/rk2t875t/2/

Comment: Here's one with the loop moved into the `setInterval()` closure: https://jsfiddle.net/rk2t875t/3/